# How can I set app wide font in ant design

Tags: css, next.js, antd

I am using NextJS 14 and I have the following:

globals.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
@layer reset {
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Then in my global layout.js file which is the entry layout into my application I have this:

```
import '../globals.css'
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server';
import React from 'react';
import { colors, fonts } from '../globalTokens.stylex';
import * as stylex from '@stylexjs/stylex';
    
const styles = stylex.create({
  html: {
    colorScheme: 'light dark',
  },
  reset: {
    minHeight: '100%',
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
  },
  body: {
    background: colors.background,
    fontFamily: "Plus Jakarta Sans" //I specified the fontFamily for my app here
  },
});

export default async function RootLayout({ children, params: { locale } }) {

  if (!locales.includes(locale)) notFound();

  return (
    <html {...stylex.props(styles.html, styles.reset)} lang={locale}>
      <body {...stylex.props(styles.reset, styles.body)}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Unfortunately the font is not getting applied on my texts and buttons in antd 5.

What do I do?

Comment: It should. Can you provide a minimal, replicable example of this issue on some online ide like https://codesandbox.io?

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sandpack-project-forked-4sf343?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wbb0006356ltun100oo%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wba0002356lp1r9cu5o%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wba0003356lsvd3du7a%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wbb0005356l1bdl4zh3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqw55wba0002356lp1r9cu5o%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wb90001356lnvv8lp2k%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wba0002356lp1r9cu5o%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqw55wb90001356lnvv8lp2k%2522%257D%252C%2522clqw55wbb0005356l1bdl4zh3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wbb0005356l1bdl4zh3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wba0004356ld981e0w9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqw55wba0004356ld981e0w9%2522%257D%252C%2522clqw55wba0003356lsvd3du7a%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqw55wba0003356lsvd3du7a%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D), My suggestions is to use Ant Design themes check the [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) .
Minimal code example

```
import { Button, ConfigProvider, Space } from "antd";
import React from "react";

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      token: {
        // Seed Token
        colorPrimary: "#00b96b",
        borderRadius: 2,
        fontFamily: `'Brush Script MT', cursive`,
        // Alias Token
        colorBgContainer: "#f6ffed",
      },
    }}
  >
    <Space>
      <Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
      <Button>Default</Button>
    </Space>
  </ConfigProvider>
);

export default App;
```